# Remote Event receiver error "There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44332/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I am developing a new remote event receiver, where i followed these steps:-

1- Inside visual studio 2015 >> create new sharepoint add-in >> provider-hosted Add-in >> i enter the url for a test enterprise wiki site collection which have the Sideloading of apps feature enabled. 
[image]

2- Then i enabled the handle Add-in installed/uninstalled:-
[image]

3- Then inside the `AppEventReceiver.svc` i entered code as follow, and the methods implementation:-

> ```
> public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
>         {
>             SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
>
>         switch (properties.EventType)
>         {
>             case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
>                 HandleAppInstalled(properties);
>                 break;
>             case SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling:
>                 HandleAppUninstalling(properties);
>                 break;
>             case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
>                 HandleItemAdded(properties);
>                 break;
>         }
>
>
>         return result;
>     }
>     // code goes here for the above methods implementation ..
> ```

4- but when i run the project >> i got an intermediate message that the app is been installed  >> then i got this error message:-

[image]

5- and when i click on the app details there was one Install Error, as follow:-

```
The remote event receiver callout failed.
Details: There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44332/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Comment: Have you followed [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/debug-and-troubleshoot-a-remote-event-receiver-in-a-sharepoint-add-in) on how to configure and debug RERs?

Comment: @TrevorSeward this link is mentioning to use azure service bus for debugging,, but this approach will no longer work... as azure service bus has been retried by Microsoft..

Comment: That's not correct for RERs. You need to follow those directions.

Comment: @TrevorSeward looks there are multiple ways to create RER now i am following the steps mentioned in this link @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ mainly by creating provider-hosted app.. but we can not use azure service bus anymore ,, and if i do so i will get the problem which i have opened another question about it https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260229/unable-to-debug-our-remote-event-receiver-using-azure-service-bus-one-or-more

Comment: @TrevorSeward any advice on the above if u have faced similar case? as the documentation about RER and mainly how to debug them after retiring the Azure service bus is almost zero...

Comment: Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-appeventreceiver

Comment: @RohitWaghela the accepted answer is referring to creating an "Azure Service Bus connection" which is no longer supported... and i can not find any alternatives ..

Comment: @RohitWaghela also the accepted answer is referencing a link which no longer exsits @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/03/21/update-to-debugging-sharepoint-2013-remote-events-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Your comments regarding Azure SB are simply not correct. You can and must create an SB namespace to perform RER debugging. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-acs-migration for more info on the impact to SharePoint (or lack there of).

Comment: @TrevorSeward now when i create RER i follow this official documentation from Microsoft https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ which mention to use azure service bus for debugging RER,, but when i followed this approach i got this error `One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server`,,,

Comment: @TrevorSeward also here are 2 questions i already created about the problems of using Azure SB  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260229/unable-to-debug-our-remote-event-receiver-using-azure-service-bus-one-or-more & https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint#74b0a3fc-739a-4f82-91e0-0237f0a6599e .. where all mentioned that Azure SB is been retired and can not be used to debug RER,, it is not my words...

Comment: @TrevorSeward so do you have any explanation why the debugging appraoch mentioned inside this official MS documentation @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/ is returning these errors `One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server`?? i am not trying to invente any thing i am just trying to follow the official docs for debugging RER,, but they are not working recently..

Comment: @Rohit Waghela any advice on my above comments?

Comment: @Trevor Seward  any advice on my above comments?

Comment: @TrevorSeward now on your last comment you mentioned `Your comments regarding Azure SB are simply not correct`.. but you did not mention why they are not correct. as in my case when i tired to debug our RER using azure service bus we got errors and there are many online links which mentioned that using azure service bus to debug RER has been reteried by Microsoft .. your reply will be highly appreciated, as we spent around 2 weeks trying to debug our RER, without reaching anything..

Comment: Sorry had to reference a laptop where I had an RER debugging on. The conn string should look like `Endpoint=sb://example.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=policyNameValue;SharedAccessKey=sharedAccessKeyValue`. This goes into the SharePoint Addin project properties under SharePoint -> Enable debugging via Microsoft Azure Service Bus.

Comment: @TrevorSeward i already tried this appraoch by creating a azure service bus and add it to my visual studio project ,, but i got these errors `One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus.
Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server`..

Comment: @TrevorSeward Here is another question on MSDN which i wrote about this problem https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint and as one of the replies mentioned `Azure Access Control Service which used to debug Remote Event Receiver with Service Bus has been retired, `.. so can u advice ? are you suggestion something different compared with what i have already tried and did not work?

Comment: Sounds like your Service Bus may not be created correctly. You can create an SB via Azure Portal today. You need to add the resource named "Service Bus". I added a Queue to my SB, then from the SB SAP created my policy there with Manage included (though I'm not certain if that is required).

Comment: @TrevorSeward i am creating the service bus correctly as follow:- login azureportal @ https://portal.azure.com >> click on "create resource" >> "Integration" >> "Service Bus">> enter the name >> select the pricing tier as "Basic" >> select subscription as "Microsoft Azure" >> after that to get the connect string >> click on the service bus i just created >> under "settings" >>"shared access policies">> copy the "Primary Connection String" which will be something as follow `Endpoint=sb:/****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=w****o=`

Comment: @TrevorSeward then i will add the connection string to my visual studio project ... so I am not sure what i am doing wrong? also i am not sure why someone inside this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint mentioned that `Azure Access Control Service which used to debug Remote Event Receiver with Service Bus has been retired`.. so is his reply wrong? side not i am working with SP online site collection

Comment: Yes, it is ultimately incorrect. There are no changes for those using ACS with SharePoint. If that person had done a tiny bit of research, they would have found this statement prominently visible.

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok.. so why it is not working for me then and i will get this error `One or more services were unregistered from the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. Cannot register Services/AppEventReceiver.svc on Microsoft Azure Service Bus: Unable to connect to the remote server` if i use azure SB? and am i creating the service bus correctly? if you can check my above 2 comments where i mentioned how i am creating the azure SB..

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing correctly or incorrectly. There's not enough information to work with. You may want to post your exact steps of creation and configuration in your original post.

Comment: @TrevorSeward i already mentioned the exact steps i am doing to create the azure SB ,, check my above comment (add 14 minutes ago)

Comment: You'll need to supply more diagnostic information, then. Again, not enough to work with to tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: @TrevorSeward i mentioned exactly what i am doing .. also here is another question on MSDN https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint where i described everything in details, so if you can have a look at it... also i read many articles that using azure SB can not be used anymore to debug RER...

Comment: Let's take this over there, then. StackExchange makes for a poor troubleshooting platform.

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok i already provided a comment inside MSDN,, on why using azure sB is not working for me,, if it is still supported?

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you advice on this problem? or on my question on MSDN https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint .. as you mentioned that using azure service bus can still be used to debug RER, but you did not explain how?

Comment: @TrevorSeward are you planning to help with this issue? or the question on MSDN https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6606300a-426f-4dec-97a7-ba76caec0ff3/one-or-more-services-were-unregistered-from-the-microsoft-azure-service-bus-cannot-register?forum=onlineservicessharepoint ? now you stopped others from commenting on this by saying that Azure service bus can still be used to debug RER and what others are saying is not correct.. but still you did not mention why i am unable to debug our RER using Azure service bus ... your advice will be highly appreciated..